# Wrong result for the emitter current

Tags: bjt, pnp

I've been given the following simple pnp transistor circuit where β=20 and Veb=0.7V and I'm trying to find the emitter current:

[image]

**I have the solutions but they don't agree with my results.**

**My attempt:**
$$V_{eb}=0.7=>V_e-V_b=0.7\\=>(10-10\times I_e)-I_b\times 1000=0.7\\=>9.3=10I_e+1000I_b\\=>9.3=10I_e+1000\frac{I_e}{β+1}\\I_e=0.161mA$$

**The solution from the manual:**
$$I_e=\frac{10V-0V}{10KΩ+\frac{1MΩ}{β+1}}=0.174mA$$

**Why are the results different? And more importantly, how exactly did the second equation come up?What does it mean?** Maybe an equivalent resistance was used there (maybe) but also, why is the voltage difference 10 in the numerator? A voltage difference of 10-(-10)=20V would perhaps make more sense, wouldn't it? Of course, I can't understand what the second equation represents so I can't make guesses.

Comment: They have also not used \$V_{eb}=0.7V\$

Comment: In the solution from the manual, what does the "0V" term represent? What voltage is this in the circuit?

Comment: I'd say your answer is closer, the manual neglected to take into account Vbe.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have no idea. All I have from the manual is what I wrote here. Maybe, if you take the Thevenin equivalent, Vth=0 ? But still, it wouldn't work out.

Comment: As for the fact that Veb=0.7 is  not used, maybe Veb was added so that the problem gets easier to solve. If there is a solution that doesn't include a specific Veb, the result may be "more correct".

Comment: @JohnKatsantas I get about \$I_{_\text{E}}\approx 161.4\:\mu\text{A}\$. So I agree with the others adding comments here and with your approach. I think the manual is wrong.